# Calculation is wrong

Tags: c#, .net, calculator

### What should happen

My exexcrise is it to prgramm a calculator which is able to do calculations in 'queue'.

Example:
User enters first number in `txtZahl` and then clicks one of the button. The needed calculation should be saved in the list `numbers` and `txtZahl` should be cleared. The user can now enter a new number and press a button etc.
When the user clicks on `btnEqu` the foreach should take every calculation from the list and do the calculation. If this is done the result should be displayed in `txtZahl`.

### Problem

The calculations are not correct. For example I get 0.00 as result for 4-3.

I know that the idea with the extra class is not the best way, but I would like to keep it, to see what my teacher thinks about it.
Thank you for helping!

Code:

Form1.cs

```
double ergebniss = 0;
Boolean firstRun = true;
List<Rechnung> numbers = new List<Rechnung>();
Rechnung.RechenArt lastArt;

private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isValid())
    {
        if (firstRun)
        {
            ergebniss = Convert.ToDouble(txtZahl.Text);
        }

        numbers.Add(new Rechnung(Convert.ToDouble(txtZahl.Text), Rechnung.RechenArt.Subtraktion));
        lastArt = Rechnung.RechenArt.Subtraktion;
        clearAndFocus();
    }
}

private void btnEqu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Rechnung r in numbers)
    {
        switch (r.getArt())
        {
            case Rechnung.RechenArt.Subtraktion:
                {
                    ergebniss -= r.getNumber();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    txtZahl.Text = ergebniss.ToString("f2");
}
```

}

Comment: Okay I tried to reduce the code and deleted some Code. I dont know where the promblem directly is, so I can't delete more. I hope this helps you a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (firstRun)
        {
            ergebniss = Convert.ToDouble(txtZahl.Text);
            firstRun = false;
            return;
        }
```

first you forgot to 
firstRun = false; after that

then I advice you to display just clean string

```
txtZahl.Text = ergebniss.ToString();
```

you also doesn't use lastArt variable don't know if that's necessary.